# Is this server specification good?

Tags: performance, load-balancing, application

Sorry for this newbie question, but I was going to order this server to run my PHP and MySQL web application, I'm doing a project for the students in my class, and it's going to have about 1000 users or more, and probably maximum 25 at one time, because of the timetable that I have, it's a sharing info website. It doesn't use videos at all, only images for the profile pictures, and text messaging updates. Plus it's going to be using memcache and a couple of optimising tweaks!

Server specification:

- CPU: Opteron 1216
- Clock Rate: 2 x 2.4 GHz
- RAM: 2 GB RAM
- Storage: 2 x 250 GB
  (RAID 1 Software)

I just wanted to know if this is okay to deal with the demand, or shall I get a better server, and any hosting solutions you know.

P.S. This is a dedicated server.

Comment: We dont know what kind of load your 25 active users are generating. This is a question thats impossible to accurate answer.

Comment: Dedicated server? Dedicated to what (or who)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be adequate.  It might get slow at heavy load, but it shouldn't DOS.

If you have the time and inclination, throw some perfmon on there and keep an eye on the performance charts over time.

Answer (score 0):

For your task (I consider the database doesn't contain many data) even one Opteron 1216 and 2 GB RAM should be enough. Of course if you aren't planning to grow your timetable into another Facebook.

Comment: no no not another facebook, but the data will grow over time,

Comment: Which kind of data, how much, will the SQL requests contain a joins?

Comment: thier is gonna be a couple of joins yes, its only text data, no blobs or nothing, im hoping it can deal witrh like 30,000 records of messages